# Is there a reasonable way for a TypeScript class to derive from a Dojo/Dijit class?

Tags: typescript, secure-coding

[DefinitelyTyped](http://definitelytyped.org/) has a Dojo solution which uses named modules and may work with legacy Dojo and explicit typing. But these declarations do not facilitate TypeScript `import`, since there are no anonymous modules. It seems to be a more exhaustive and consistent version of [schungx/Dojo-TypeScript](https://github.com/schungx/Dojo-TypeScript), but without the declared modules which make `import` work.

[schungx/Dojo-TypeScript](https://github.com/schungx/Dojo-TypeScript) does not allow for 'extends' of an `import` Dijit but provides both named and anonymous declarations.

[Brian Forbes](https://github.com/bryanforbes/dojo-typescript) provides a `dijit.d.ts` definition which is good at consuming `dijits` from TypeScript.  His solution is available [here](https://github.com/bryanforbes/dojo-typescript). It works perfectly well with `import`, since it uses anonymous module declarations, but still does not allow for TypeScript inheritance (even the incompatible type).

The following code allows me to develop TypeScript wijits that extend `ContentPane` that actually work (despite the inheritance compatibility).

```
declare module "dijit/layout/ContentPane"
{
    class w extends dijit._Widget {
        addChild(w: dijit._WidgetBase, index?: number);
    }
    export = w;
}
```

It extends the _Widget class defined in [schungx/Dojo-TypeScript](https://github.com/schungx/Dojo-TypeScript) and tricks `tsc` into thinking the `ContentPane` is a TypeScript class.

This is what extends means (`d` is derived class, `b` is base class):

```
var __extends = this.__extends || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    __.prototype = b.prototype;
    d.prototype = new __();
};
```

The derived class gets all base properties, including prototype.  But I've been warned several times that this is unsafe.

My questions:

- Is it really unsafe?
- Is there a reasonable approach to making this safe?  I don't believe my [Typescript Hack to extend ContentPane](https://gist.github.com/ca0v/1d1a2ae8a43f4e0bc1c7) is reasonable.

Comment: Did the folks who advised you that this approach was unsafe explain why they thought so?

Comment: The gist of the concern was keeping it compatible with future version of the framework and making sure the component would work in various scenarios.  I got it working and so I used it.

Comment: That's odd reasoning. It is always possible code might not work with future versions...

Comment: It's been chugging along for the past 6 years so it worked out pretty well for me.  We are still on 1.11 using the ESRI JSAPI 3.x so there never really was a future version in our future.